# Convert Nested CSS Array to String in PHP

Tags: php, css, arrays

I have an issue where I can't seem to correctly convert my Array back to a string. I keep ending up with formatting issues out the wazoo.

I found what I thought would do the job, but it is only exporting out the first item in the array as opposed to all items in the array and it is also including extra attributes.

Here is what I am running:

```
<?php  
/**
 * Converts a multidimensional array of CSS rules into a CSS string.
 *
 * @param array $rules
 *   An array of CSS rules in the form of:
 *   array('selector'=>array('property' => 'value')). Also supports selector
 *   nesting, e.g.,
 *   array('selector' => array('selector'=>array('property' => 'value'))).
 *
 * @return string
 *   A CSS string of rules. This is not wrapped in <style> tags.
 */
function grasmash_generate_css_properties($rules, $indent = 0) {
    $css = '';
    $prefix = str_repeat('  ', $indent);

    foreach ($rules as $key => $value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
        $selector = $key;
        $properties = $value;

        $css .= $prefix . "$selector {\n";
        $css .= $prefix .grasmash_generate_css_properties($properties, $indent + 1);
        $css .= $prefix . "}\n";
      }
      else {
        $property = $key;
        $css .= $prefix . "$property: $value;\n";
      }
    }
    return $css;
  }                    
$css = "
.text_1_1 {
    width: 419px;
    height: 101.5px;
    background-size: 1459.5px 632.5px;
    background-position: -486px -255.5px;
  }
  .text_1_2 {
    width: 393.5px;
    height: 49.5px;
    background-size: 1459.5px 632.5px;
    background-position: -7px -398.5px;
  }
";
preg_match_all( '/(?ims)([a-z0-9\s\,\.\:#_\-@]+)\{([^\}]*)\}/', $css, $arr);

$result = array();
foreach ($arr[0] as $i => $x)
{
    $selector = trim($arr[1][$i]);
    $rules = explode(';', trim($arr[2][$i]));
    $result[$selector] = array();
    foreach ($rules as $strRule)
    {
        if (!empty($strRule))
        {
            $rule = explode(":", $strRule);
            $pxless = str_replace("px","", trim($rule[1]));
            $arr = explode(" ", $pxless);
            for($j=0; $j<count($arr); $j++) $arr[$j]=($arr[$j]/2)."px";
            $finally = implode(" ", $arr);
            $result[$selector][][trim($rule[0])] = $finally;
        }
    }
}   
$finalCss = grasmash_generate_css_properties($result);
print $finalCss
?>
```

Which gets me close to a solution but the print is:

```
.text_1_1 {
  0 {
      width: 209.5px;
  }
  1 {
      height: 50.75px;
  }
  2 {
      background-size: 729.75px 316.25px;
  }
  3 {
      background-position: -243px -127.75px;
  }
}
1 {
}
```

I feel like the foreach loop is just missing a level to it and that is why I am only getting the first item as well as the incorrect formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your code. The first (and most important) is that you are overwriting your `$arr` array in the loop which generates `$result`:

```
$arr = explode(" ", $pxless);
```

You need to rename it e.g.

```
$pxlarr = explode(" ", $pxless);
for($j=0; $j<count($pxlarr); $j++) $pxlarr[$j]=($pxlarr[$j]/2)."px";
$finally = implode(" ", $pxlarr);
```

The second (which causes the digits in your output) is that you are unnecessarily generating an extra layer in your `$result` array with

```
$result[$selector][][trim($rule[0])] = $finally;
```

This should be just

```
$result[$selector][trim($rule[0])] = $finally;
```

If you fix these two issues, the output of your code is:

```
.text_1_1 {
  width: 209.5px;
  height: 50.75px;
  background-size: 729.75px 316.25px;
  background-position: -243px -127.75px;
}
.text_1_2 {
  width: 196.75px;
  height: 24.75px;
  background-size: 729.75px 316.25px;
  background-position: -3.5px -199.25px;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UupVR)